# How do I output csv file in a tidy manner? (python3, jupiter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pip

When I try to output my table csv table, it looks horrible. What should I do?

I tried just putting it in, but it's really messy.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = df.read_csv(r"C:\yourpath\data.csv")

df
```

[image]

I want to get something more readable such as:

[image]

I tried putting some formatting in the excel file, but it doesn't seem to save this things because of the csv format

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  If your question includes a pandas dataframe, please provide a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: you need the `sep=';'` parameter documented here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Hi! Your problem is less the output but more the import of the csv file. Your example does not look like pandas got the columns right, so please refer to the pandas help page https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html. A a guess, I think you need to include `names` and `sep` to correctly read your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 
df = df.read_csv(r"C:\yourpath\data.csv", sep=";")

df
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).